# Where are users located

Tags: discussion

Is there anyway to get a general idea of where in the world the user base is located? Looking for the possibility of breaking it down percentage wise in order to get a better understanding of how much of the user base is in different areas of the world.

The reason I am asking this is due to recent questions wondering about political leaning of the site and having a better understanding of where in the world the user base lives could help answer the question better.

Comment: The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) can be used to search the location that users set in their profile (see [this similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60876/finding-stack-overflow-exchange-users-based-on-geographic-area) for more info), however it's data that's completely up to the user to write so it'd be hard to parse and wouldn't be fully accurate (there are almost 14000 users who've set a location, and they range from full addresses to stuff like 'A Subaru Forester heading south').

Comment: The [Stack Overflow Developer Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020#geography) has both self-reported nationality and site visit information, but it's focused on Stack Overflow users and it's unclear how much overlap there is with politics

Comment: @Giter I was thinking it would be possible for stack exchange itself to get more accurate information based on the ip address that users have when they visit the site as the information you mentioned can be fake if the person wants it to be.

Comment: @divibisan Yep and while that info may not be that interesting for a lot of sites I think it would be for this one.

Comment: @Giter I am not asking for that information but more along the lines of 50% of the users are from the US, 40% are from EU possibly breaking it down by country. I think that how the breakdown is world wide could be useful info

Comment: @JoeW: When it comes to discussing politics, a lot of people *really like* anonymity. I don't think the Politics site wants to give the impression that they are digging into ip addresses to establish users' locations; it might have a chilling effect. Impressions matter...

Comment: @TedWrigley I understand that but saying where the user base in general is doesn't break that anonymity. And there is no reason why people should not already have the impression that Stack Exchange isn't tracking your login information as they use Google Analytics and that is something that is collected.

Comment: @JoeW: There may be "no reason why people should not already have the impression...", but invoking a double-negative does not create a positive. People (as a rule) don't like being reminded of things they choose not to think about.

Comment: Are you asking just about the (registered) users or including the (unregistered) visitors?

Comment: Well I think it would mainly be registered users as the question revolves around those who can comment, vote and take other actions on posts.